# If $\log_{72}144=a$. Compute $\log_{1001}501^{2019!}$

Tags: logarithms

Surfing on the web i found a question that i think is bit interesting :0
The problem:
If $\log_{72}144=a$. Compute $\log_{1001}501^{2019!}$

I tried to factorize $72, 144, 1001$ and $501$, but $1001=7*11*13$ and $501=3*167$, and i couldn't figure it out more than this, can someone help me with this nice question?

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: I do not see how the "If ..." part is related to the demanded computation. (Also, $a = 1 + \log_{72}2$.)

Comment: Do you have a link to the problem?

Comment: Me neither, i don't know the source too :/

Comment: I don't think it can be represented in terms of $a$ as $7, 11, 13$ are prime numbers. Because of this, you won't be able to split it into those bases.

Comment: Your question is too broad

Comment: Maybe you can use $log_a^b=(log_a^c)*(log_c^d)*(log_d^b)$

Answer (score 0):

It will be enormous.  $\log_{1001}501 \approx 0.8998$, so the number you want is about $0.8998 \cdot 2019!$  [Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log%281001%2C501%29*2019%21) says it is about $1.71988 \cdot 10^{5798}$.  It will give you lots more digits if you want.  I don't know how to use $a$ in this.

Comment: In the given question by using the formula above we can conclude that $log_{1001} ^{501}= a*log_{1001} ^{72} *log_{144} ^{501}$. Ie., $log_{1001} ^{501}=0.77431*a$.

Comment: @Ch.SivaRamKishore:  Yes, but usually when questions are asked like that the variable assigned is useful, giving a simpler form of the answer.  Here there seems no relationship between $a$ and the value we are to evaluate.